# Typescript add static metadata to a class and read at runtime

Tags: angular, typescript

Can someone please show me how I can create a custom decorator in Typescript that appends static metadata to the type which I can read at runtime (without instantiating an instance of the class) in the same way the `__annotations__` works in Angular.

Update - see image below. How can I create my own decorator factory on the type? I can find plenty of examples where decorators add data to the constructed instance but not the actual type.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a decorator factory or [type annotations](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-annotation) help in that case?

Comment: @iLuvLogix, yes how do I create a decorator factory that appends data to the actual type not the instance? I cannot find any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sussed this, coming from a .net background I just hadn't fully appreciated that you can treat the target/class like any other javascript object, and the constructor looks to me like it is just another special kind of method on the object.

```
export function MyDecorator(metadata: any) {
  return (target) => {
    if (!target[`__my_annotations__`]) {
      target[`__my_annotations__`] = {};
    }

    target[`__my_annotations__`].metadata = metadata;

    return target;
  };
}
```

The above works for me, hope this saves someone the time I lost on this.